# restoring ubuntu boot logo

Tags: boot, logo

After installing Ubuntu 14.04,I installed `kubuntu-desktop` so I can choose between unity and KDE. But now the kubutu logo appears when I turn on the computer. How can I restore the ubuntu logo (which appears when the computer is booting up)?

Comment: Is this the login screen?

Comment: It appears before log in screen. I cannot take a screen shot.

Answer (score 3):

Paste the following command into a terminal and select the desired splash image by typing its number:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
```

I guess `/lib/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo-scale-2.plymouth` is the default.